# Are these two statement TRUE for all functions f and for all subsets A and B of the domain of f?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Are these two statement TRUE for all functions $ f $ and for all subsets $ A $ and $ B $ of the domain of $ f $ ?

i)  { $f(x): x ∈ A \} - \{ f(x): x ∈ B \}$ is a subset of { $f(x): x ∈ A - B$ }

ii) { $f(x): x ∈ A - B$ } is a subset of { $f(x): x ∈ A \} - \{ f(x): x ∈ B \}$

- I proved both of these wrong by using:

$ f(x)=2x  $,        $ A = \{1, 2, 3 \}$,
$ B = \{1, 2, 3 \}$

for { $f(x): x ∈ A \} - \{ f(x): x ∈ B \}$

$ f(x) = \{ 2,4,6 \}$ for both $ A = \{1, 2, 3 \}$,
$ B = \{1, 2, 3 \}$

$ A-B = \{2,4,6\} - \{2,4,6\} = \{ \} $

for { $f(x): x ∈ A - B$ }

$ A-B = \{2,4,6\} - \{2,4,6\} = \{ \} $

$ f(x)=\{\} $

- Thus, these two statements are wrong as empty set is not a empty set to another empty set. (empty set is a subset to every set, but is it a subset to an another empty set?)

Comment: Note that $A=B\iff \{A\subset B\}\cap\{B\subset A\}$. So saying $\emptyset\subset\emptyset$ is fine.

Answer (score 0):

$\emptyset$ is a subset to all sets, including $\emptyset$. Your proof is therefore incorrect.

Also, there is some confusion in your words when you say that an empty se is not an empty set to **another** empty set.

There is **only one** empty set. And for that emptyset, which we usually denote as $\emptyset$, it is true that $\emptyset\subseteq \emptyset$. This is true by the very definition of the subset relation. Remember, a set $X$ is a subset of $Y$ if the following is true: $$\forall x: (x\in X\implies x\in Y).$$

Well, in the case of $X=\emptyset$, the statement $x\in X$ is always **false**. Therefore, no matter what statement $S$ we take, the statement $x\in X \implies S$ will be **true** (because of how implication works). In particular,  taking $S$ to be "$x\in Y$" will make the statement we want, and we now know it is true. Therefore, no matter what $Y$ we take, we know that $\emptyset\subseteq Y$. In particular, because we know this is true for **all** sets, it must also be true for $Y=\emptyset$, so we know that $\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset$.

Comment: So for this question, can I say that, in both statement, x is an element of A, also, x is element of B, (A) - (B) give nothing , (A - B) also gives nothing because x belongs in both A and B.Thus, both the statemets are correct?

Comment: @Kwongcc I don't know which statements you are refering to when you say "the statements", so I cannot answer your question.